# Exclude on a many-to-many relationship through a third table

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a problem making "exclude" querys on tables which have a many-to-many relationship through a third table. I have a table with projects, a table with people and a relationsship table with the flags "is_green, is_yellow, is_red", like:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, through='Status')

class Status(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    is_green = models.BooleanField()
    ...
```

Now I want to make a query returning all persons, excluding those which do have the flag "is_red" in a specific project. But the following

```
Person.objects.exclude(project=p, status__is_red=True)
```

excludes everyone who is registered at project *p* but has status=red for **any** project he is registered. Is there a way to tie the second condition to the first?

My approach was to filter on the Status table directly, which works of course. But then I do have a list of "Status" objects instead of "Person" objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this? (untested)

```
Person.objects.exclude(id__in=Person.objects.filter(project=p, status__is_red=True).values(id))
```

Comment: Great! This idea works as desired. Although the syntax has to be slightly modified, because values() gives a list of dicts (at least in v1.0). This gives the exact result:
Person.objects.exclude(id__in=Person.objects.filter(project=p, status__is_red=True).values_list('id', flat=True))

Comment: Ah, yes... You are right on using values_list. I'm sorry. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of Status objects called 'objects', you can use

```
[s.person for s in objects]
```

to make it into a list of the corresponding Persons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that is exactly what I want to avoid. The question is, if there is a possibility get the list of Persons in one statement.